# MUI customize Select in TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

What is wrong in the following code?

```
TS2322: Type '(event: SelectChangeEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: SelectChangeEvent<unknown>, child: ReactNode) => void'.   Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
     Type 'SelectChangeEvent<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'SelectChangeEvent<string>'.
       Type 'Event & { target: { value: unknown; name: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'SelectChangeEvent<string>'.
         Type 'Event & { target: { value: unknown; name: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Event & { target: { value: string; name: string; }; }'.
           Type 'Event & { target: { value: unknown; name: string; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ target: { value: string; name: string; }; }'.             The types of 'target.value' are incompatible between these types.
               Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.


 Select.d.ts(104, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { items: { children: ReactNode; props: MenuItemProps<"li", {}>; }[]; } & SelectProps<unknown>'
```

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MuiSelect, {SelectProps as MuiSelectProps} from '@mui/material/Select';
import MuiMenuItem, {MenuItemProps as MuiMenuItemProps} from '@mui/material/MenuItem';


export type SelectProps<T = unknown> = {
    items: {
        children: React.ReactNode,
        props: MuiMenuItemProps,
    }[],
} & MuiSelectProps<T>;

const Select: React.FC<SelectProps> = ({items, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <MuiSelect
            {...props}
        >
            {
                items.map((item, index) => (
                    <MuiMenuItem key={item.props.key ?? index} {...item.props}>{item.children}</MuiMenuItem>
                ))
            }
        </MuiSelect>
    );
};

export default Select;
```

This is the `onChange` prop

```
const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
        // Some logic
    };
```

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the error? Is it on the `<MuiSelect {...props}` bit?

Comment: In my custom `Select` in the `onChange`, `<Select onChange={handleChange} ....>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `SelectChangeEvent` with no type parameter will result in the default value, `string` (see below), which is not compatible with the inferred type `unknown` - what you get when calling your `Select` component. You can fix this by using `SelectChangeEvent<unknown>` in `handleChange`.

---

### Explanation

The trouble `T` type parameter passed to `MuiSelectProps` is the culprit. Looking at [Select.d.ts](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Select/Select.d.ts), `T` is used here:

```
  onChange?: SelectInputProps<T>['onChange'];
```

Which points to

```
/**
 * The change can be caused by different kind of events.
 * The type of event depends on what caused the change.
 * For example, when the browser auto-fills the `Select` 
you'll receive a `React.ChangeEvent`.
 */
export type SelectChangeEvent<T = string> =
  | (Event & { target: { value: T; name: string } })
  | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;

export interface SelectInputProps<T = unknown> {
  // ...
  onChange?: (event: SelectChangeEvent<T>, child: React.ReactNode) => void;
```

So when you call `SelectChangeEvent` sans a type parameter, it defaults to `string` while `unknown` is inferred as the default type parameter for all the parent usages.

Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhA2EDGwDCALAhgOwOYQFEA3CbYAHgBUoBeKAZ2ACcBLPAPloCgooAfKAApipYFABkUAN5RgmJvmAAuaVCKZ4AVwgrKAbijZMAWx0NmbXFAC%20NgJR6uXNsAhMAZpiTQ4iFAElsME1gAAUmAHsweipaKE1sAGtsCIB3bE4pHigAehyoADoi7IjsDBx8AH4VQQgSMhVfZDQsPEJ6ikp2O1pOIgiWABNHaycXN09vWARm8KiY6joE5LSM6WzeUvK26um-YEDgsMjoqnYAbQByLdb8S4BdEadB5Hh5aHcElBZSveazwRgE70RozFBzU5dOwqHAgJygSBQCELOLLFLpTh0LK8XgsVzGEHSazne4AGi4tkkTXBwLOji4SFKjCgACF5DUwCpkT0aJxYXFBFI8RACaTCkUgfNrDzMhs-ihAcCHBSnGymIKoMKCSoSWKbhUzLUOqD9tt8CIyOQ0atODKidKuGqNVrCbqoPq2jU6qITc0ze1RFA7VJrA6uEA) with this.

Comment: I have not been able to get mine to work how I'd expect. And I notice an open bug: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33399

Comment: https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-component-changes/#update-event-type-typescript-3